# Algorithm to take out every other word in a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

In Javascript, if I have a string like so: "Hello nice to meet you"
And what I would like returned to me are the words in odd places so I would get: "Hello to you"

How would I be able to write the code for this?

Comment: I have already answered this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51839163/10217138

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to create a new array with elements that have an even index.

Just remember that the words in "odd" places are actually located at even indexes, since arrays in javascript are zero-indexed.

```js
var s = 'Hello nice to meet you'

var evenWords = (s) => s.split(' ').filter((element, index) => index % 2 === 0).join(' ');

console.log(evenWords(s))
```

Answer (score 3):

A very simple array based solution, is given below:

```js
var arr = "Hello nice to meet you"
var outStr = ""; 
arr = arr.split(' ');

// filter out all elements that are located at an even index in the array.

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i = i + 2){
   outStr = outStr + arr[i] + ' ';
}
outStr.trim();
console.log(outStr)
```