# how to find the alternate words in a sentence using javascript

Tags: javascript

If there is a sentence " hello how are you dear "
then i want the output as "hello are dear" .How can i do this ? 
I have tried this code

```
var codelines = response.split(" ");
var firstWords = [];

for (var i=0;codelines.length / 2;i++)
{
  var words = codelines[i].split("|").join("\n");
  firstWords.push(words);
}
alert(firstWords);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `split` and `map` to do this. Split to get the string into chunks of words and then filter this array and take out required elements.

```js
const sentence = " hello how are you dear ";

const getAlternate = (sentence) => {
  return sentence.trim().split(" ").filter((e,i) => i%2===0).join(" ");
}

console.log(getAlternate(sentence));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex with pattern `\w+` for retrieving the word list then remove all words on even indexes with `filter`.

```js
console.log(" hello how are you dear ".match(/\w+/g).filter((word, i) => i % 2 === 0).join(' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

**@swathi** you are on right direction but little misguided:

Your modified code:

```
var response = "Hello how are you dear"

//always trim you data first otherwise your logic will fail
var codelines = response.trim().split(" "),
    firstWords = [], 
    words="";

for (var i=0; i<codelines.length; i++) {   
  // distinguish odd position, use 1 for even ones
  if(i%2 === 0){
    words = codelines[i];
    firstWords.push(words); 
  }
}
alert(firstWords.join(' '));
```

> P.S: There can be many possible solution to this problem. My code is just to let you know where you went wrong.

**Edit:** As pointed out by @Cerbrus, you can also reduce complexity by half using following loop:

```
for (var i=0; i<codelines.length; i+=2) {   
   words = codelines[i];
   firstWords.push(words);
}
```

Cheers:)

Comment: Instead of `i++`, how about using `i += 2`? Then you wouldn't need the `if`.

Comment: That is even better with O(n/2) complexity. As I wrote above, there can be any number of possible solutions.

Answer (score -1):

Simple Javascript Below:

```js
var sentence = "hello how are you dear";
var arr = sentence.split(" ");
var newArr = [];

for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i+=2){
  newArr.push(arr[i]);
}
console.log(newArr);
```

The "newArr" array contains the required words.

Comment: Something wrong with my answer?